# ErrorException preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 28

Tags: php, laravel, routes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b06pK.png)

When I open register page => http://localhost:8000/auth/register
, I see this error message..

> ErrorException preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in
>   character class at offset 28

I think, this message is routes/web.php error. Is it right?
Since, I made coding auth/register, auth/login.... appear this error message. 
before that, I didn't see this message.
Can you advice for me?

Laravel 6, php7.4

web.php

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'root',
    'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index'
    ]);

// Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
]);

Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');

/* Markdown view */
Route::get('docs/{file?}', 'DocsController@show');
Route::get('docs/images/{image}', 'DocsController@image')
        ->where('image', '[\pL-\pN\._-]+-img-[0-9]{2}.png');

/* 사용자 가입 */
// Route::get('auth/register','UsersController@create')->name('users.create');
Route::get('auth/register', [
    'as' => 'users.create',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@create'
]);

Route::post('auth/register', [
    'as' => 'users.store',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@store'
]);
Route::get('auth/confirm/{code}', [
    'as' => 'users.confirm',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@confirm'
]);

/* 사용자 인증 */
Route::get('auth/login', [
    'as' => 'sessions.create',
    'uses' => 'SessionsController@create'
]);
Route::post('auth/login', [
    'as' => 'sessions.store',
    'uses' => 'SessionsController@store'
]);
Route::get('auth/logout', [
    'as' => 'sessions.destory',
    'uses' => 'SessionsController@destroy'
]);

/* 비밀번호 초기화 */
Route::get('auth/remind', [
    'as' => 'remind.create',
    'uses' => 'PasswordsController@getRemind'
]);
Route::post('auth/remind', [
    'as' => 'remind.store',
    'uses' => 'PasswordsController@postRemind'
]);
Route::get('auth/reset/{token}', [
    'as' => 'reset.create',
    'uses' => 'PasswordsController@getReset'
]);
Route::post('auth/reset', [
    'as' => 'reset.store',
    'uses' => 'PasswordsController@postReset'
]);
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <form action="{{ route('users.create') }}" method="POST" role="form" class="form__auth">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="이름" value="{{ old('name') }}" autofocus/>
            {!! $errors->first('name', '<span class="form-error">:message</span>') !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="이메일" value="{{ old('email') }}"/>
            {!! $errors->first('email', '<span class="form-error">:message</span>') !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="비밀번호"/>
            {!! $errors->first('password', '<span class="form-error">:message</span>') !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="비밀번호 확인" />
            {!! $errors->first('password_confirmation', '<span class="form-error">:message</span>') !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">
            가입하기
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my regular expression problems.

```
->where('image', '[\pL-\pN\._-]+-img-[0-9]{2}.png');
->where('image', '[\pL\-\pN\._-]+-img-[0-9]{2}.png');
```

I missed '\' .